# How to use DSC to confgure httpErrors defaultPath

Tags: powershell, iis, dsc

In a DSC configuration script for IIS, I am trying to remove the defaultPath lock from the httpErrors section but the way in which the feature delegation works does not apply to this section. Hence to do the following:

```
appcmd set config /section:httpErrors /lockAttributes:
```

I've tried using the xWebConfigProperty as follows:

```
xWebConfigProperty httpErrors_lockAttributes
{
    WebsitePath = "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
    Filter = "system.webServer/httpErrors"
    PropertyName = "lockAttributes"
    Value = ""
    Ensure = "Absent"
}
```

However this fails with an error saying the lockAttributes attributes does not exist. And yet it is definitely in the ApplicationHost.config

My only remaining workaround is to run the appcmd as Script in the DSC (a little ugly). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use below PowerShell command to remove lock from the default path:

```
Remove-WebConfigurationLock  -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/httpErrors/@defaultPath"
```

Comment: I agree this works, but so did the appcmd command, but I was seeking a DSC configuration script to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old as all heck. But what I've found is a lot of these modules and resources were built for specific tasks and are less modular than other DSC tools. You may have to create a custom resource that handles Remove-WebConfigurationLock in its set/get/test functions if you want a "pure" DSC solution. If not, a DSC script resource will do what you need.